# how to add multiple transaction in CollectSignaturesFlow

Tags: kotlin, corda

I have finished building of two transaction using Transaction builder with two different state and contract respectively in single flow. Now Am trying to add those transaction to CollectSignaturesFlow to get counterparty signatures. But I couldn't.

Comment: Sounds to me you are trying to make two transactions atomic, note that `CollectSignaturesFlow` precisely only collect the signatures. you could do it separately, however `FinalityFlow` is where the transactions get notarize, as far as i know Corda is making sure we notarize one transaction at a time to prevent double spending.

Comment: thank you @Rickky13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectSignaturesFlow` only takes one transaction at once. To collect signatures on two different transactions, you'd have to do:

```
val signedTx1 = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx1, signerSessions1)
val signedTx2 = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx2, signerSessions2)
```